# Getting Response nil In Quickblox apns sendmessage

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

Using this to send message

[QBMessages TSendPushWithText:@"text" toUsers:@"1474494" delegate:self];

Getting  this Response
all is nil

self    MainViewController *    0x155b3040  0x155b3040
result  QBMSendPushTaskResult * 0x155f02f0  0x155f02f0
NSObject    NSObject
isa Class   QBMSendPushTaskResult   0x001cb4e4
request Request *   nil 0x00000000
NSObject    NSObject
isa Class   0x0 
answer  Answer *    nil 0x00000000
NSObject    NSObject
errors  NSMutableArray *    nil 
query   QBQuery *   nil 
NSObject    NSObject
delegate    NSObject *  nil 
canceler    NSObject *  nil 
isCanceled  BOOL
canceledLock    NSRecursiveLock *   nil 
context id  0x0 
requestBuildStyle   RestRequestBuildStyle

Comment: please provide a full Xcode log

Comment: hello igor but solved my problem and your sdk is great.